# Why does RSA authentication work after deleting private key?

Tags: linux, ssh

I was testing my authorized_hosts setup, so deleted my local private key. I then successfully ssh'd into my remote server using RSA authentication.

I was expecting to get a permission denied, seeing as there is no longer a private key to guarantee I'm me. Guessing I'm misunderstanding something fundamental. Anyone know what's going on?

It doesn't look like ssh-add is holding my private key:

```
jake@clyde:~$ sudo pkill -9 ssh-agent
```

Comment: `ssh-add -L` lists the public key for any private keys that are loaded; showing the actual private key would probably be insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignacio's suggestion got me thinking. If ssh-agent might be caching my private key (which was proven to not be the case), what else might be? The culprit, of course, was gnome-keyring-daemon. There may be a more elegant way, but smashing it with a hammer felt good (kill -9). *Now* attempting RSA authentication without a private key in existence fails as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your private key may have been loaded into the SSH agent running on your machine. Use `ssh-add -L` to verify.

Comment: Are you saying if I see the public key when running `ssh-add -L`, then the private key is loaded? I ran `ssh-add -D` to delete all identities from ssh-add. It had no effect. `root:# pkill -9 ssh_agent` also had no effect on my ability to remotely login.

Comment: @djeikyb: fyi, it's not `ssh_agent` but `ssh-agent`.

Comment: Bugger. No matter. Eris knows why, but I kill nined the pid after each pkill, just to be sure. `ps auxw|grep ssh` showed only the keyring command by the end, which is how I narrowed it down.